# Use CarouselDialog without installing Recon SDK?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, carousel

I need a CarouselDialog in my application. Based on what I've read, I can only use that if I install the recon SDK. But said SDK uses only API 16 and I have some parts of my code where I need a higher API than that. Is there any SDK/libraries available that I can download/install so that I can use CarouselDialog?

I've thought of just using a Modal view and make the background of an activity (that uses a CoverFlow) transparent but I want to try and use CarouselDialog since it's more appropriate.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: You could just copy out the relevant bits and pieces from the [SDK source](http://repo.reconinstruments.com/artifactory/libs-release/com/reconinstruments/ui/recon-ui/4.3.1/recon-ui-4.3.1-source.jar)? Based on a quick glance it's just a simple `DialogFragment` wrapping a customised `ViewPager`. Searching for `CarouselViewPager` turns up several other promising results too.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize ViewPager fit my needs. Thanks!